# ActiveBatch ExecutePowerShellScript convert byte array to string

Tags: .net, powershell, encoding, arrays

I'm trying to use the ActiveBatch **ExecutePowerShellScript** job step to convert a `System.Byte[]` to a string.  The ActiveBatch job step has a property to specify the `InputObjects`, which I set to the output of the previous job step (this is just a field in the job steps editor, not PowerShell code). Then you apparently have access to a variable called `$input` in the PowerShell script..

With just `$input` I get a list of bytes converted to integers.  With `$input | gm` I get:

```
There are 25 output objects generated by the Powershell script

   TypeName: System.Byte[]

Name           MemberType    Definition                                         
----           ----------    ----------                                         
Count          AliasProperty Count = Length     
Address        Method        System.Byte&, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture...
```

If I try `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($input)` I get:

> Exception taken executing PowerShell script: Cannot find an overload
>   for "GetString" and the argument count: "1".

If I try `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString(,$input)` I get:

> Exception taken executing PowerShell script: Missing ')' in method
>   call.

If I try:

```
[byte[]]$bytes = $input
[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString($bytes)
```

I get:

> Exception taken executing PowerShell script: Cannot convert the
>   "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineReader`1+<GetReadEnumerator>d__0[System.Object]"
>   value of type
>   "System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineReader`1+d__0[[System.Object,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]" to type "System.Byte[]".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$bytes = $input | Select-Object
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($bytes)
```

Apparently you have to use `Select-Object`, and the byte array was coming through as ASCII rather than unicode.